# django change field by variable

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys

I have this:

```
class Character(models.Model):
    weapon = models.ForeignKey(item, related_name='weapon')
    shield = models.ForeignKey(item, related_name='shield')
    ...

class Item(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    choices = (
        ('weapon', 'weapon'),
        ('shield', 'shield'),
        ...
    )
    typeOf = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=choices)
    ...
```

I would like to update my character field by the name of the item.typeof like this but it doesn't work.

```
character[item.typeof] = item
character.save()
```

how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use built-in [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) function:

```
setattr(character, item.typeOf, item)
character.save()
```

Comment: doesn't work too, it give me **name 'typeof' is not defined**

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that uppercase `O`.  Change line to `setattr(character, item.typeOf, item)`